# Create an Linked List array of linked lists with a loop java

Tags: java, loops, linked-list

I have successfully implemented Radix sort but I have the following code that I would like to convert to be created by a loop.

```
private static LinkedList[] bucket = { 
        new LinkedList(), // -9
        new LinkedList(), // -8
        new LinkedList(), // -7
        new LinkedList(), // -6
        new LinkedList(), // -5
        new LinkedList(), // -4
        new LinkedList(), // -3
        new LinkedList(), // -2
        new LinkedList(), // -1
        new LinkedList(), // 0
        new LinkedList(), // 1
        new LinkedList(), // 2
        new LinkedList(), // 3
        new LinkedList(), // 4
        new LinkedList(), // 5
        new LinkedList(), // 6
        new LinkedList(), // 7
        new LinkedList(), // 8
        new LinkedList() // 9
};
```

However I cannot figure out how I might go about doing this.
I tried this but I get compiler errors.

```
private static LinkedList[] bucket;
int thing = 19;
while(thing != 0){
    bucket = new LinkedList();
    thing--;
}
```

This is not critical to the functionality of my radix sort as it works flawlessly, I just think it would be cleaner to initialize my buckets with a loop.  That said if someone could enlighten me on how to do this I would be very grateful.

Comment: `bucket = new LinkedList();` bucket is an array not a LinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
private static LinkedList[] bucket = new LinkedList[19];

static {
    for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; ++i) {
        bucket[i] = new LinkedList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. Might I ask though why the ++i instead of i++?

Comment: @Azethoth In this scenario, it makes no difference and is simply a matter of style.

Comment: In this case it makes no difference. In some cases `++i` is more efficient than `i++`, so I use that as a habit.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I did not think it mattered, but on the chance it did I wanted to know why since there is a difference between pre and post fix operations.

Comment: The pre-fix operator can update the counter and return its value. The post-fix operator must cache the original value of the counter, increment the counter and return the original value. This caching can be inefficient, depending on the implementation. So if I don't specifically need the original value, I use the pre-fix version.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinkedList[]` bucket is not initlaized,so you will get `NullPointerException` at runtime.Also,the syntax of array element assignment is wrong

```
private static LinkedList[] bucket = new LinkedList[20];
int thing = 19;
while(thing != 0){
    bucket[thing] = new LinkedList();
    thing--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First set up how big the array is going to be (how many `LinkedList`s are going to be in it), then iterate from zero to that size, and set indices of the array to be new `LinkedList`s.

For example, if `i` is your iterator variable, you would say:

`bucket[i] = new LinkedList();`

Remember what types you're dealing with: a single `LinkedList`, and an array of them. You can't just assign the entire array to one `LinkedList`. You have to assign the elements to `LinkedList`s, to match types.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I feel silly for forgetting array basics.